# Show colored output in terminal when using the sh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

color.sh

```
 RED='\u001b[31m'
 GREEN='\u001b[32m'
 BLUE='\u001b[34m'
 YELLOW='\u001b[33m'
 WHITE='\u001b[37m'

 # use echo -e to print in certain colors
 echo -e ${RED} RED
 echo -e ${YELLOW} YELLOW
 echo -e ${GREEN} GREEN
 echo -e ${BLUE} BLUE
 echo -e ${WHITE} WHITE
```

When typing `$ ./color.sh` the terminal outputs in the respective colors. However, when I type `$ sh color.sh` it does not output in the correct colors. Instead it gives me the output below.

```
-e \u001b[31m RED
-e \u001b[33m YELLOW
-e \u001b[32m GREEN
-e \u001b[34m BLUE
-e \u001b[37m WHITE
```

Is there any way to make `$ sh color.sh` print in the respective colors? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this codes

```
 RED='\e[31m'
 GREEN='\e[32m'
 BLUE='\e[34m'
 YELLOW='\e[33m'
 WHITE='\e[37m'
```

But better use `printf`

```
printf "${RED} RED\n"
printf "${YELLOW} YELLOW\n"
printf "${GREEN} GREEN\n"
printf "${BLUE} BLUE\n"
printf "${WHITE} WHITE\n"
```

Also take a look [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color)

Comment: `DEF='\e[0m'` from that bash color page is useful